# Can you have a singleton as a subclass in java

Tags: java, singleton, subclass

how do you have a singleton pattern in a subclass? For example in the code below itemCatalog extends item. I want to use the getPrice getter of class item

```
public class ItemCatalog extends Item{

   private static ItemCatalog instance = new ItemCatalog(); 
   private Item itemCatalog[] = new Item[9];


   private ItemCatalog(){
   }

   public static ItemCatalog getInstance(){
      return instance;
   }

   public void populateCatalog(){  
      itemCatalog[0] = new Item("bb","Baked Beans",35);
      itemCatalog[1] = new Item("cf","Cornflakes",100);
      itemCatalog[2] = new Item("s0","Sugar",50);
      itemCatalog[3] = new Item("tb","Tea Bags",115);
      itemCatalog[4] = new Item("ic","Instant Coffee",250);
      itemCatalog[5] = new Item("b0","Bread",50);
      itemCatalog[6] = new Item("s0","Sausages",130);
      itemCatalog[7] = new Item("e0","Eggs",75);
      itemCatalog[8] = new Item("m0","Milk",65);
    }

   public void searchCatalog(String itemCode){  

      for (int i = 0; i < itemCatalog.length; i++){
          if (itemCode.equals(itemCatalog[i].getItemCode())){
             price = itemCatalog[i].getItemprice();
             break;
          }
      }   
   }
```

Edit 2:  I want to have this class as a singleton and a subclass of the item class which is not a singleton.

When I place the super(String itemCode, String description, int price) in the constructor I get an error

Edit 3: Ok I think i solve the issue with these lines of code. I am new to java..stilling practicing and learning :) ...thank everyone for your insight

```
private ItemCatalog() {

    }
   private ItemCatalog(String itemCode,String description, int price){
       super(itemCode,description, price);
   }
```

Edit 4: I'm not sure if this is correct but wanted to use the getPrice method in class item to return the result of searchcatalog which is a price. Would this be the correct design?

Comment: What's the problem with code?

Comment: Why have you made `getInstance` synchronized, and why is there a semi-colon after your constructor?

Comment: You already have singleton here. You can make `ItemCatalog` final so nobody can create subclassed of `ItemCatalog`.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want this to be a subclass? A subclass usually is a specialization (Vehicle -> Car, Bus or Pet -> Cat, Dog). An instance of a subclass inherits all fields and methods of its parent-classes. I see your Item class has some kind of Id, name and price. So your instance of the ItemCatalog also has an id, name and price. I understand you want is a singleton, but I don't see the reason for it to be a subclass from Item. Can you explain the reason for that design decision?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is correct but wanted to use the getPrice method in class item to return the result of searchcatalog which is a price. Would this be the correct design?

Comment: Don't let ItemCatalog be a subclass of Item. Instead, in Item you can write `price = ItemCatalog.getInstance().searchCatalog(this.itemCode);`

Comment: and don't let `searchCatalog` be a void method, rather have it return the price it finds.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the question is but...

If you make the instance field `final` you don't need to `synchronized` the getInstance()

If a static field is final, the reference is initialised in a thread safe way and cannot change so you don't need to lock anything to access it.

Comment: I want to have this class as a singleton and subclass of item

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov It is thread safe but a field which might be changed is not.

Comment: @Adesh That is what you have, so I don't understand what the question is.

Answer (score 0):

Your design needs to change. The Catalog needs to be separate from an Item.

Comment: I wanted to use the getPrice method in class item to return the result of searchcatalog which is a price. Would this be the correct design?

Comment: No. The item only knows about itself. The catalog is the collection of items. Searching for an item? Ask the catalog. Want to know the details of an item (the price)? Ask the item.  Want to get all the items with a price of X? Ask the catalog.